# Which studio strobes are compatible with the Yongnuo YN-622C?

Tags: canon, yongnuo, studio, strobes, monolights

I currently have 2 pairs of Yongnuo YN-622C Wireless TTL Flash Triggers for Canon. I'd like to use them to wirelessly trigger studio strobes and I'm wondering if anyone knows the compatibility of the different monolights with these units. I tried using them with a pair of Impact 300Ws but couldn't get them to work at all. Possibly I'm not using them properly? I'm shooting with a Canon 60D and it doesn't have a PC port, (what's up with that anyway??) so I used a YN-622C and a PC cable to sync one from camera to the strobe and had misfires and random firing issues. I ended up bagging it and turned the slaves on the units and bounced my flash off the ceiling... totally a newbie in the studio here... I'd like to get some monolights, and and I see Yongnuo has one but I'd prefer them to have a built-in battery pack, anybody know if there are other options?

Comment: You'll do a lot better here on Photo.SE if you separate out multiple questions into, well, multiple questions. I'd recommend editing this one to be just about using the YN-622C triggers with monolights.

Answer (score 1):

All studio strobes are compatible with YN-622C's.  YN-622C's are overkill though because the studio strobes will not be able to take full advantage of the ETTL and HSS features. You really just need a simple radio trigger.

Yes, you may be using them improperly.

To make the YN-622C's work with your 60D and strobes you just need to mount one YN-622C in the hotshoe. (no need for a PC cord)

The other YN-622C will need a PC cord in order to trigger the studio slaves.

Comment: "To make the YN-622C's work with your 60D and strobes you just need to mount one YN-622C in the hotshoe. (no need for a PC cord)

The other YN-622C will need a PC cord in order to trigger the studio slaves."

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for your response!  I connected one YN-622C transmitter on my camera's hotshoe, and the other YN-622C on the monolight with the proper PC cord, and exactly nothing happened... I checked that they were on the same channel...and still did not get a result. So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, or if it's a compatibility issue? (I watched a youtube video on how to do this, and it seemed so easy peasy....)

Answer (score 1):

The PC sync ports on a YN-622C are *output*-only, **not input**.  They are solely to be used to hook a flash up to a receiver 622 unit, **NOT** to be used as an output signal from a camera hotshoe.  If you want to sync over a PC cable, you have to get a hotshoe-to-PC adapter for your camera, and then cable the hotshoe to the flash's PC port.

To use YN-622C units with a studio flash, you put a YN-622C as your transmitter unit on the camera flash hotshoe. Then you cable the PC connector on your receiver YN-622C unit up to whatever sync connector the monolight uses--most typically 3.5mm miniphone or 6.35mm phone connector, but could also be household (HH), or just about any connector that can communicate a simple short.

A quick checklist for radio triggers misfiring:

1. Are all the batteries in everything (camera, flashes, and trigger) in good health and fully charged?
2. Set both units to the same channel. Then, off the camera and flashes, does hitting the TEST button on your transmitter unit fire the receiver unit? If not, your triggers may be bad.
3. Connect the receiver to the studio flash with the PC cable. Make sure all connectors are fully seated.  Does hitting the test button on your transmitter fire the flash? If not, the cable or ports are probably the issue.
4. Connect the transmitter to your camera. Check that the unit is fully seated (push it forward as far as it will go).  Is your camera's flash menu control set to use flashes in M mode (not TTL)?  Studio strobes cannot do TTL, HSS, 2nd curtain, etc.  You have to have the camera assuming the flash is in M.  Does firing the camera fire the flash? If not, something may be mis-set, the unit may be misseated, or your hotshoe may need cleaning.

See also: [The Other Yongnuo YN-622C User Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/view) and [the YN-622C/YN-622C-TX thread on POTN](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1386562).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, inkista.The first part of your response really helped me understand what the PC output on the transmitters are meant to be used for! But as far as the rest, I think I did try exactly that... I connected one YN-622C transmitter on my camera's hotshoe, and the other YN-622C on the monolight with the proper PC cord, and exactly nothing happened... I checked that they were on the same channel, and tried different channels, but nothing, nada, zip. (I watched a youtube video on how to do this, and it seemed so simple....)

Comment: @M.Lutz, since we can't see how your gear is set up by telepathy, and asking you individual questions one by one isn't how this works, I've added a general troubleshooting checklist, and some references, so you can try and suss it out yourself. Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks again for your response, the checklist and the link to the Other User Guide, I found it immensely helpful!